# how to execute two foreach loops simultheneously

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

These are my two arrays.

```
 array 1  ::

       Array ( [0] => Array ( [questionID] => 103 [answer] => Female [answer_cnt] => 9 ) [1] => Array ( [questionID] => 103 [answer] => Male [answer_cnt] => 11 ) );

 array 2  ::

       Array ( [0] => Male [1] => Female )
```

I want to print output like this :

```
Female : 9
Male :11
```

Where Female and Male Comes from second array.

Could you help me please?

Comment: As Female and Male are also both in the first array, why do you need to loop both arrays?

Comment: this makes no sense whatsoever. Let's start from the beginning. What's `Male`? Is that a string? an object?

Comment: The output you want to print doesn't require 2 foreach loops

Comment: both arrays are comes as MySQL query output!

Comment: BTW - Some people are not male nor are they female

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that both of these arrays can come from MySQL output, so let's assume that there may be more than just the two rows in each of these arrays and adopt a more flexible solution.

At a simple level, it looks like what you're trying to do is loop through the first array and echo out a limited set of values based on the appearance of those values in another array.

You can do this fairly simply using a combination of [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$answers = array(
    array(
        'questionID' => 103,
        'answer'     => 'Female',
        'answer_cnt' => 9
    ),
    array(
        'questionID' => 103,
        'answer'     => 'Male',
        'answer_cnt' => 11
    )
);

$genders = array(
    'Male',
    'Female'
);

// Loop through the answers, checking each to see if they have
// a match in the gender array
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    if (in_array($answer['answer'], $genders)) {
        echo $answer['answer']. ": " . $answer['answer_cnt'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Female: 9
Male: 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to do this?

```
$arr1 = Array (0 => Array ('questionID' => 103 ,'answer' => 'Female','answer_cnt' => 9 ),
1 => Array ('questionID' => 103 ,'answer' => 'Male' ,'answer_cnt' => 11 ,));

$arr2 = Array (0 => 'Male' ,1 => 'Female');

$male = $arr2[0] .':'. $arr1[1]['answer_cnt'];
$female = $arr2[1] .':'. $arr1[0]['answer_cnt'];

echo $female.'</br>';
echo $male;
```